# Hooking fopen() function throws Segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, shared-libraries

I'm trying to log access to a particular directory by hooking the fopen() function and using LD_PRELOAD.

1. My first question is: Is hooking fopen() enough to log operations that open a file?
2. My code throws Segmentation fault. In particular, the code is like this (ignoring error checks): 
    
   `FILE* (my_fopen)(const char filename, const char* mode);
   void* libc_handle;

   void __attribute__ ((constructor)) init(void){
      libc_handle = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY); 
      *(void**)(&my_fopen) = dlsym(libc_handle,"fopen"); 
   }
   FILE* fopen(const char* filename, const char* mode){
      printf("Hello world\n"); 
      return my_fopen(filename, mode); 
   }`

After compiling and specifying the new library in LD_PRELOAD, I ran

`ls`

and it throws Segmenation Fault. Any idea why that happened? I even tried to remove the  `printf()`, but did not help.

Comment: I would hook `open` rather than `fopen`.

Comment: Did you consider inotify?

Comment: @MatteoItalia, I did hook open, but it wasn't used to open the file. I think fopen() and the like use the private method \__open() which i don't think i can hook into

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some issues in your code, which are fixed in the sample below (I've also added the relevant headers and provided a `main` to give a complete program):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

FILE* (*my_fopen)(const char *filename, const char* mode);
void* libc_handle;

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) init(void){
   libc_handle = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
   my_fopen = dlsym(libc_handle,"fopen");
}
FILE* fopen(const char* filename, const char* mode){
   printf("Hello, Pax\n");
   return my_fopen(filename, mode);
}

int main (void) {
   FILE *fout = fopen ("xyzzy.txt","w");
   fclose (fout);
   return 0;
}
```

The changes from what you provided are as follows:

- The `my_fopen` function pointer should be exactly that, a pointer. I suspect you may have thought the `FILE*` made it so but that's not actually correct. To specify a ffunction pointer returning a `FILE` pointer, you need `FILE * (*fn)(blah, blah)`.
- Similarly, the first argument of that function must be a `const char *`, a *pointer* in other words. You had it as simply `const char`.
- You don't actually need that convoluted expression for setting the `my_fopen` pointer (casting, taking address of, de-referencing). You can just use the much simpler `my_fopen = ...`. In fact, I think the casting may be actually what's preventing `gcc` from reporting an error in this case since it's assuming, if you cast, that you know what you're doing.
- You probably should also check the return value of `dlopen`. I haven't done that in this code but, if you don't find (or can't load) the library for some reason, the line after that will probably cause you grief.

When I compile and run this program on `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.4 (Santiago)`, I get the output of `Hello, Pax` *and* the file `xyzzy.txt` is created.

---

And, just as an aside, there are other functions which may be used to gain access to the file-system, things like `open`, `opendir`, `freopen`, `creat`, `mkfifo` (I think).

Depending on your needs, you may have some extra work to do.

---

One thing you *may* want to consider is that `ls` may not even *use* `fopen`. It can actually be built with just `opendir/readdir` and `stat`.

So, let's use a program that we *know* calls `fopen`. Enter the following program `qqtest.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
   FILE *fh = fopen ("xyzzy.txt", "w");
   fclose (fh);
   return 0;
}
```

and compile it with `gcc -o qqtest qqtest.c`, then run it. You should see no output but the file `xyzzy.txt` should be created. Once you've confirmed that, delete the `xyzzy.txt` file, then enter the following program `qq.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

FILE* (*my_fopen)(const char *filename, const char* mode);
void* libc_handle;

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) init(void){
   libc_handle = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
   my_fopen = dlsym(libc_handle,"fopen");
}

FILE* fopen(const char* filename, const char* mode){
   printf("Hello, Pax\n");
   return my_fopen(filename, mode);
}
```

Compile this with `gcc -shared -o qq.so qq.c -ldl` and then run your `qqtest` program (changing the shared object path to your own directory of course):

```
LD_PRELOAD=/home/pax/qq.so ./qqtest
```

This time, you should see the `Hello, Pax` string output before the `xyzzy.txt` file is created, proof that it's calling your wrapper function, which in turn calls the original `fopen`.

---

Now, that's all very well but, even once you get this bit working, you have to intercept quite a few different calls to ensure you catch all changes.

That's going to take you quite a while to get done and, as Chris Stratton points out in a comment, the Linux kernel already *has* the capability to report file-system changes to you.

If your goal is to just track file-system changes rather than educate yourself on how it could be done, look into [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) to see how to do this *without* having to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: thanks, but it was a mistake of editing (the code wouldn't have compiled had I not include the return). Just edited my question, still the same error.

Comment: @user1734905, have looked into it more deeply, see the update.

Comment: did you test it with "ls" ? I still have the Segmentation Fault error with "ls"

Comment: @user1734905, type in the code exactly as I have it and test it, then use that as a baseline. Second, there's no guarantee that `ls` uses `fopen`, so you may want to check that. I suspect you could build `ls` using only `opendir/readdir` and `stat`.

Comment: @user1734905, I've provided a full test suite for you and confirmed that `ls` does not use `fopen` (at least on its own with no arguments). I suggest you try again with the code more suited to your environment (shared object with `LD_PRELOAD` rather than my original stand-alone executable).

Comment: it now works for fopen(). I tried to run a Java application that opens and writes to a text file, but the Java code invoked neither open(), fopen(), openat(), opendir(), etc.. I'll try other approach for my origin goal.